# How to merge values on datetime column whilst taking average

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge my columns by a datetime column, `date`,  whilst taking and average on the yearly_cost columns. My `df` looks as such:

```
        date        yearly_cost_x  yearly_cost_y  yearly_cost
0     2009-01-01        5               7              3
1     2009-01-02        8               7              4
2     2009-01-03        23              6              6
```

I wish to merge the df by `'date'` and once merge take an average of the 3 values to create a single value for every row in a columns named `Yearly_Cost`. I feel this should be easy but am somehow struggling and receiving several errors.

I wish for my df output to looks as such:

```
        date        Yearly_Cost
0     2009-01-01        5
1     2009-01-02        6.33
2     2009-01-03        11.66
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

ADDITION:

I have a column with multiple dates and one `yearly_cost` column as such. It looks as such:

```
        date        Yearly_Cost
0     2009-01-01        5
1     2009-01-02        6
2     2009-01-03        11
3     2009-01-01        12
4     2009-01-02        45
5     2009-01-03        32
```

I wish for it to look this this:

```
        date        Yearly_Cost
0     2009-01-01        8.5
1     2009-01-02        25.5
2     2009-01-03        21.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `mean` per rows with `axis=1` and last for `DataFrame` is used [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('date').mean(axis=1).reset_index(name='Yearly_Cost')
print (df1)
         date  Yearly_Cost
0  2009-01-01     5.000000
1  2009-01-02     6.333333
2  2009-01-03    11.666667
```

If possible another non `yearly` columns filter columns by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('date').filter(like='yearly_').mean(axis=1).reset_index(name='Yearly_Cost')
```

Comment: I now have the opposite problem. I have multiple dates in the column `date` and wish to merge all the dates taking average of singular column `Yearly_Cost`.  I have tried to switch the answer but it doesn't work. Why is this?

Comment: @geds133 - Use `df = df.groupby('date')['Yearly_Cost'].mean().reset_index()      `

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
df['Yearly_Cost'] = df['Yearly_Cost'].apply(lambda x : (x['yearly_cost_x']+x['yearly_cost_y']+x['yearly_cost'])/3 )
df.drop(['yearly_cost_x','yearly_cost_y','yearly_cost'],axis=1)
```